# Fatal: Server unexpectedly closed network connection

Tags: powershell, file-upload, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to run following command from SQL Server Agent job to upload daily files to our FTP server. I tried the connection from a local utility like WinSCP 5.1.5 and connection to FTP succeeds without any problems, however connection attempt from script fails (following is code and error). Can someone help me in the right direction please?

```
$Error.Clear();
$csv_file = "FilePath"
$sftp_cmd = "C:\psftp.exe"

$user = "TestUser"
$pass = "pwd"
$hst = "ftp3.xyz.com"
$cmd = @(
  "put $csv_file",
  "bye"
)

$cmd | & $sftp_cmd -pw $pass "$user@$hst" -batch
```

I am always getting an error

> Fatal: Server unexpectedly closed network connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is working fine for me. However, your question suggests that you're trying to connect to an FTP server. WinSCP can handle both SCP/SFTP and FTP connections, but to my knowledge `psftp` supports only [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) (a file transfer protocol based on SSH, not to be confused with [FTPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ftps)).

If your server is not an SSH server, you need an FTP client for the data transfer (e.g. `ftp.exe` shipped with Windows). If your server is an SSH server, try running `psftp` with the option `-v` to get more information, and also check the logs on the server.

Comment: Sorry, my bad; it's a SFTP infact. Turned out to be a network issue. Its working good.